# Are constraints for constrained Delaunay triangulation actually respected

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm using the Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2 for a simple set of points and constraints. Are the constraint segment that I provide using insert_constraint() guaranteed to be returned when I iterate through each edge and call is_constrained() on them? I would expect that if segment (5 8) (2 5) is a constraint that if I queried that edge, it would be a constrained edge.

In my example below, I provide 5 constraints but I receive 6 edge constraints. Could this be due to approximation errors? Thanks.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 CGALPoint;
typedef K::Segment_2 CGALSegment;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, CGAL::Default, 
CGAL::No_intersection_tag> CDT;
typedef CDT::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
...
CDT* cdt = new CDT();
Vertex_handle v0 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(5, 8));
Vertex_handle v1 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(0, 4));
Vertex_handle v2 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(1, 9));
Vertex_handle v3 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(0, 1));
Vertex_handle v4 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(10, 3));
Vertex_handle v5 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(1, 1));
Vertex_handle v6 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(4, 7));
Vertex_handle v7 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(3, 9));
Vertex_handle v8 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(2, 5));
Vertex_handle v9 = cdt->insert(CGALPoint(4, 10));

cdt->insert_constraint(v0, v8); // (5 8) (2 5)
cdt->insert_constraint(v0, v3); // (5 8) (0 1)
cdt->insert_constraint(v1, v9); // (0 4) (4 10)
cdt->insert_constraint(v1, v3); // (0 4) (0 1)
cdt->insert_constraint(v6, v3); // (4 7) (0 1)

for (CDT::Edge_iterator eit = cdt->edges_begin(); eit != cdt->edges_end(); ++eit) {
    CDT::Edge e = *eit;
    if (cdt->is_constrained(e))
        std::cout << "Constraint   ";
    else
        std::cout << "Unconstraint ";

    CGALSegment s = cdt->segment(e);
    const CGALPoint& p1 = s.point(0);
    const CGALPoint& p2 = s.point(1);
    std::cout << "(" << p1 << ") (" << p2 << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Output (re-ordered for readability)

```
Constraint   (4 10) (0 4)
Constraint   (0 1) (0 4)
Constraint   (2 5) (4 7)
Constraint   (0 1) (4 7)
Constraint   (5 8) (0 1)
Constraint   (4 7) (5 8)
Unconstraint (0 4) (1 9)
Unconstraint (0 4) (2 5)
Unconstraint (2 5) (4 10)
Unconstraint (4 10) (1 9)
Unconstraint (1 9) (3 9)
Unconstraint (3 9) (4 10)
Unconstraint (1 1) (0 1)
Unconstraint (4 10) (10 3)
Unconstraint (4 7) (4 10)
Unconstraint (10 3) (1 1)
Unconstraint (0 4) (3 9)
Unconstraint (5 8) (4 10)
Unconstraint (5 8) (10 3)
Unconstraint (5 8) (1 1)
Unconstraint (0 1) (2 5)
```

Comment: You have intersecting constraints, so they get split.

Comment: Ah! That seems to be the case. Thank you. I wonder if there is a way to enforce that a constraint segment is not broken up into two edges.